# Extract the names of rejected variables from step function

Tags: r, regression, glm

I use step function on a glm object

```
stepglm<-step(glmmodel)
```

and step rejects 2 variables from glmmodel. Is there a way to extract the names of the rejected variables from stepglm object? It seems that stepglm is just a glm object so perhaps there is no easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `stepAIC` in the MASS package.  Here is an example:

```
library(MASS)

example(birthwt) # construct bwt

birthwt.glm <- glm(low ~ ., family = binomial, data = bwt)
birthwt.step <- stepAIC(birthwt.glm, trace = FALSE)
as.character(birthwt.step$anova$Step)[-1]
## [1] "- ftv" "- age"
```